# Preventing Entity Framework Code First generating extraneous Foreign Key, without using Fluent?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following POCOS with the given relationship:

```
ProductTransferHistory [1-*] <-- ProductTransferHistoryEntry [1-*] <-- WipEntry
```

The code is as follows:

```
public class ProductTransferHistory
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ProductTransferHistoryId { get; set; }

    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(ProductTransferHistoryEntry.ProductTransferHistory))]
    public ICollection<ProductTransferHistoryEntry> ProductTransferHistoryEntries { get; set; }

    public IList<ProductTransferHistoryEntry> EntriesWithName => ProductTransferHistoryEntries.Where(x => x.Name != null).ToList();
}

public class ProductTransferHistoryEntry
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ProductTransferHistoryEntryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProductTransferHistoryId))]
    public ProductTransferHistory ProductTransferHistory { get; set; }

    public Int32 ProductTransferHistoryId { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }        

    [InverseProperty(nameof(WipEntry.ProductTransferHistoryEntry))]
    public virtual ICollection<WipEntry> WipEntries { get; set; }

    public IList<WipEntry> NonZeroWipEntries => WipEntries.Where(x => x.Quantity != 0).ToList();
}

public class WipEntry
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 WipEntryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProductTransferHistoryEntryId))]
    public ProductTransferHistoryEntry ProductTransferHistoryEntry { get; set; }

    public Int32 ProductTransferHistoryEntryId { get; set; } // associated entry of ProductTransferHistoryId

    public Decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

For some reason the when I add a migration, for the ProductTransferHistoryEntries table, it is generating two foreign key columns: *ProductTransferHistoryId*, and a _ProductTransferHistory_Id_ column. And on the *WipEntry* table it is creating two FK columns *ProductTransferHistoryEntryId*, and _ProductTransferHistoryEntry_Id_. In both cases the second FK is nullable, which also does not make sense.

The problem seems to be the collection nav properties. I thought that the "InverseProperty" annotation would solve the program, but it is still generating the extra FK. If I remove the nav collection properties, the extra columns are not generated, but that isn't a solution, as I need those properties for my LINQ to Entities.

I have seen a few solutions that solve the issue using the fluent API. But I am wondering if there is an annotation that can solve the problem?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code you provided. I have generated everything perfectly with your code in my side. May be problem is causing due to any other relations that you did not mentioned in the code.

Comment: It turns out that a derived Nav property was causing the problem. e.g., `NonZeroWipEntries => WipEntries.Where(x => x.Quantity != 0);` I added a NotMapped attribute to it and it fixed the issue. I just assumed that because there was no setter, it would not be needed. I updated the code in the question so that this can hopefully help someone else.

Comment: Yeh! Great to hear that your problem has been fixed! shall I post my comment as answer?